# How to make case insensitive username authentication in hybris?

Tags: java, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud

How to make case insensitive username authentication in hybris?

Answer (score 4):

First you have to override the register method of DefaultCustomerFacade (file in commercefacades).

You will find that default implementation force lower case preventing you from having upper case characters in your uid -->
`customer.setUid(registerData.getLogin().toLowerCase())`

Then you have to create a new bean with alias "acceleratorAuthenticationProvider" that override the method authenticate.

In this method you have to implement something like

```
final UserModel userModel = findUserCaseInsensitive(authentication.getName());
if (userModel != null)
{
    usernameResult = userModel.getUid();
    token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials());
    token.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());
}
```

The method `findUserCaseInsensitive` should call a DAO that will perform a flexible search.
Here is an example :

`SELECT {user.PK} FROM {User as user} WHERE lower({user.uid}) = lower(?uid)`